# parsing a string to get a number and getting different results

Tags: objective-c, ios

i'm parsing a string that looks like this:

```
POINT(-96.795894101604 46.911266990766)
```

when i parse the 2 numbers out, i get different values based on if i use a double or a [NSNumber numberWithDouble:]

```
-(void)parseGPSValue:(NSMutableString *)GPSString
{
    NSRange prefixMatch = [GPSString rangeOfString:@"("];
    NSRange midMatch = [GPSString rangeOfString:@" "];
    NSRange sufixMatch = [GPSString rangeOfString:@")"];

    //parses the GPS coords; NSMakeRange takes starting location and range
    double latitude = [[GPSString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange((prefixMatch.location + 1), ((midMatch.location - 0) - (prefixMatch.location + 1)))] doubleValue];
    double longitude = [[GPSString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(midMatch.location + 1, (sufixMatch.location) - (midMatch.location + 1))] doubleValue];

    NSString *temp1 = [GPSString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange((prefixMatch.location + 1), ((midMatch.location - 0) - (prefixMatch.location + 1)))];
    NSString *temp2 = [GPSString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(midMatch.location + 1, (sufixMatch.location) - (midMatch.location + 1))];

    NSNumber *tempLat = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[temp1 doubleValue]];
    NSNumber *tempLong = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[temp2 doubleValue]];

    NSLog(@"GPSString: %@", GPSString);

    NSLog(@"latitude: %g| longitude: %g|", latitude, longitude);
    NSLog(@"NSNumber lat: %@, NSNumberLong: %@", tempLat, tempLong);
}
```

results are:

```
2012-03-26 10:33:10.166 GPSString: POINT(-96.795894101604 46.911266990766)
2012-03-26 10:33:10.167 latitude: -96.7959| longitude: 46.9113|
2012-03-26 10:33:10.168 NSNumber lat: -96.79589410160401, NSNumberLong: 46.911266990766
```

why do i get a more precise value when the NSString/NSNumber way then using a double?

Comment: A double is not precise. Use decimal if you really care for precise floating point values. Edit: sorry I thought this was about c# :) Maybe the same applies here.

Comment: I don't see that you're getting different results.  In the first case you're just getting default 6.4 formatting precision.  Change the formatting precision and the numbers will be much more similar (if not identical).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
if (latitude == [tempLat doubleValue]) {
    NSLog(@"same");
}
if (longitude == [tempLong doubleValue]) {
    NSLog(@"same");
}
```

the difference of string representations doesn't mean the difference of values.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can simplify your code into:

```
double latitude = [temp1 doubleValue];
double longitude = [temp2 doubleValue];

NSNumber *tempLat = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:latitude]; // Can't be more precise than latitude 
NSNumber *tempLong = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:longitude]; // Can't be more precise than longitude 

NSLog(@"latitude: %g| longitude: %g|", latitude, longitude);
NSLog(@"NSNumber lat: %@, NSNumberLong: %@", tempLat, tempLong);
```

Notice that in fact, you get the value of `tempLat` and `tempLon` from `latitude` and `longitude` so they can't be more precise than them.

The only problem is in that you are printing the values of `latitude` and `longitude` using the format `%g`. Try another formatting precision and you will see more decimals:

```
NSLog(@"latitude: %.12f| longitude: %.12f|", latitude, longitude);
// latitude: -96.795894101604| longitude: 46.911266990766|
```

Comment: i knew the code could be simplified, i was just testing so wasn't too concerned about it. when i use %f, i got the same precision, tried using %g and just left it. you are right, it is just a formatting "error", where the object will print more digits then double will. as Michex pointed out, when compared directly they are equal.

Comment: I simplified the code to show that you get the value of `tempLat` from `latitude `. That means that `latitude` can't have *"less"* precision. The same applies for `longitude` and `tempLong`.